# Linq update issue with lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to write some code in Linq with lambda.This is my first code using lambda and i am facing an issue while updating Record.
My code  is:

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{

    Table<NOTIF_RECIP> NOTIF_RECIP_alias = db.GetTable<NOTIF_RECIP>();
    Table<NOTIF_SCHED> NOTIF_SCHED_alias = db.GetTable<NOTIF_SCHED>();
    Table<mainframe_replication> mainframe_replication_alias = db.GetTable<mainframe_replication>();

    var ids = NOTIF_SCHED_alias.Select(x => x.NOTIF_RPT_ID).ToArray();


    foreach (string notif_sched_data in ids)
    {
        var repljoinmf = mainframe_replication_alias
                        .Join(NOTIF_RECIP_alias,
                             mfr => mfr.RPT_ID,
                             nr => nr.NOTIF_RECIP_ID,
                             (mfr, nr) => new
                             {
                                 ReportId=mfr.RPT_ID, 
                                 Reportversion=mfr.RPT_VERS,
                                 ReportBytes= mfr.RPT_BYTES.ToString(), 
                                 ReportDate=mfr.REPL_DTM.ToString(),
                                 NotifId= mfr.NOTIF_ID,
                                 RecipAdd=nr.NOTIF_RECIP_ADDR
                             });

        foreach(var repljoinmf_data in repljoinmf)
        {
            //DO STUFF 
            repljoinmf_data.NotifId = "Changedxyz";
            //db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting Error in `repljoinmf_data.NotifId = "Changedxyz";`
Error says: **Error 2   Property or indexer 'AnonymousType#3.NotifId' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only**

Can someone please help me in this.I think it is because I am using var which is anonymous but how to solve the problem.Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `var` is not _anonymous_, it just means "let the compiler decide what the type is"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, anonymous class instances cannot be modified once they have been projected.

Although you could switch to a strong typed class, and then reassign the member properties, however, you have an opportunity to project the desired result in the preceding LINQ statement into the same anonymous class:

```
var repljoinmf = mainframe_replication_alias
.Join(NOTIF_RECIP_alias, mfr => mfr.RPT_ID, nr => nr.NOTIF_RECIP_ID, 
(mfr, nr) => new // Anon Class projection
{ 
    ReportId=mfr.RPT_ID, 
    Reportversion=mfr.RPT_VERS,
    ReportBytes= mfr.RPT_BYTES.ToString(),     
    ReportDate=mfr.REPL_DTM.ToString(),
    NotifId= "Changedxyz", // *** No need to mutate this afterwards
    RecipAdd=nr.NOTIF_RECIP_ADDR 
});
```

**Edit, Update isn't trivial assignment, suggested alternatives**

*Option #1 : Strongly typed Class with mutation after projection*

Add a new class (I've guessed some types)

```
public class MyPoco
{
     public int ReportId {get; set;}
     public string Reportversion {get; set;}
     public byte[] ReportBytes {get; set;}
     public DateTime ReportDate {get; set;}
     public int NotifId {get; set;}
     public string RecipAdd {get; set;}
}
```

Which you can then project into (just specify the class name instead of anonymous):

```
(mfr, nr) => new MyPoco // Not anonymous
{ 
    ReportId=mfr.RPT_ID, 
    ...
```

And then do modification afterwards:

```
foreach(var repljoinmf_data in repljoinmf)
{
  repljoinmf_data.NotifId = "SomeNewValue"
```

*Option #2 - Create a method (or Func) which does the complex logic*

Since you seem to have already materialized all the data, you are free to use complex functions in the property projections. Any of the available local variables (closure) are available to pass to thus function, as are the join lambda parameters `(mfr, nr)`

So for example, write a function to calculate your `NotifId = "Changedxyz"` replacement:

```
private string DoIntensiveLogic(mainframe_replication mfr, NOTIF_RECIP nr)
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

Which you can then use in your original anonymous projection:

```
(mfr, nr) => new // Anon Class projection
{ 
    ReportId=mfr.RPT_ID, 
    Reportversion=mfr.RPT_VERS,
    ReportBytes= mfr.RPT_BYTES.ToString(),     
    ReportDate=mfr.REPL_DTM.ToString(),
    NotifId= DoIntensiveLogic(mfr, nr), // Call the function each row
    RecipAdd=nr.NOTIF_RECIP_ADDR 
});
```

Comment: Thanks but what i need is to change the value of Notifid everytime based on some conditions.I do not want it to be fixed as "Changedxyz".

Comment: I've updated with two ways to achieve this. I would prefer the second option as it avoids the new class and also does the projection in one step. Changing the result afterwards imperatively always looks a bit nasty IMO.

Comment: Thanks Sir.you are life saver.Everything works now but wheni call **db.SubmitChanges()** ,no change in database.Am i missing something else?Thanks again

Comment: Can you please have alook why it is not getting submitted in db please.Stuck with that now.I know different question but dont want to post a new one.Thanks again Sir

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous types are `immutable` and hence created cannot be changed you have to  create a new type.
To solve your issue you have to create your own type and avoid the use of anonymous type when a future update is needed.
your type may  look  like this

```
public class  ReportInfo
{
   public  int Id{get; set;} 
//the same thing  for others properties 
}
```

and your  query  will look like this

```
new ReportInfo() { 
                Id = mfr.RPT_ID, 
                Reportversion = mfr.RPT_VERS,
                ReportBytes = mfr.RPT_BYTES.ToString(), 
                ReportDate = mfr.REPL_DTM.ToString(),
                NotifId = mfr.NOTIF_ID, 
                RecipAdd = nr.NOTIF_RECIP_ADDR 
            })
```

than you can  update easily your  property

```
 foreach(var repljoinmf_data in repljoinmf)
        {
            //DO STUFF 
             repljoinmf_data.NotifId = "Changedxyz";
           //db.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

**More about anonymous Types**
what the compiler is actually doing. When you write a line of code like this:

```
var o = new { property1 = expression1, ..., propertyN = expressionN };
```

the compiler infers the type of each expression, creates private fields of these inferred types, creates
public read-only properties for each of the fields, and creates a constructor that accepts all these
expressions. The constructor’s code initializes the private read-only fields from the expression results
passed in to it. In addition, the compiler overrides Object’s Equals, GetHashCode, and ToString
methods and generates code inside all these methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir,But my bad can`t mark as answer as only one is possible.Thanks a lot between

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change 'NotifId' later, you can find a record by id and change the property.

Example:

```
var alias = mainframe_replication_alias.SingleOrDefault(mfr => mfr.NOTIF_ID == repljoinmf_data.NotifId);
if(alias != null)
   alias.NOTIF_ID = "Changedxyz";
```